# Getting error "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: response for class: com.school.ClassService

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy

I am getting the below error while reading the data from the rest call
Error:-groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: response for class: com.school.ClassService. Although my rest call is success because I can see logs in the called API:-

```
    Map<String, Object> httpRequestBody = new HashMap<>();
        httpRequestBody.put("name", otherParams.username)
        httpRequestBody.put("roll", otherParams.roll) 
        log.debug(httpRequestBody)
        String studentURL = https://dev-student/api/detail/student/marks"
        log.debug("URL")
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpRequestBody,headers)
        log.debug(entity)
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.exchange(studentURL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class)
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.debug(e.printStackTrace())
        }
     
        log.info(response)
```

marksController.java

```
@PostMapping("/student/marks")
public String generateTotalMarks(@Valid @RequestBody StudentMarksRequest studentMarkRequest) throws Exception  {
    
    return caService.getMarks(studentMarkRequest);
```

Comment: This means that in current scope there is no variable named "response" or you are trying to access a property "response" of some object, which does not exist.

Comment: I am just printing logger outside the try catch

Comment: Please include the entire code which is causing an issue in order to be able to help you.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `response` object is not available outside of the try-catch block.

Any variable which is declared within the try-catch block is only visible within this block. Rewrite your code as follows and it should work:

```java
    Map<String, Object> httpRequestBody = new HashMap<>();
        httpRequestBody.put("name", otherParams.username)
        httpRequestBody.put("roll", otherParams.roll) 
        log.debug(httpRequestBody)
        String studentURL = https://dev-student/api/detail/student/marks"
        log.debug("URL")
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpRequestBody,headers)
        log.debug(entity)
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.exchange(studentURL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class)
        log.info(response)
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.debug(e.printStackTrace())
        }
```